# python Selenium SendKeys() issue for sending "-" key

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium to automate form auto-fill option on example.com

but what i see is, selenium **send_keys()** is not sending all the characters to browser

input to send_keys() function is : **תל אביב -יפו** and

what selenium writes to browser page is : **תל אביב יפו**

it omits the dash(-) from string

can someone point me to the right direction as to how can i have selenium to send all the characters to browser

```
element.clear()
element.send_keys(u'תל אביב -יפו')
```

this is what **keys_to_typing** generates as input to **Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT**

```
[u'\u05ea', u'\u05dc', u' ', u'\u05d0', u'\u05d1', u'\u05d9', u'\u05d1', u' ', u'-', u'\u05d9', u'\u05e4', u'\u05d5']
```

Comment: It may have to do with the encoding.... I don't see this issue when it's encoded as utf-8

Comment: I don't find any problem, it sends fine! I am using selenium-webdriver Ruby Bindings.

Comment: Yes I tested writing this input to other html forms and its Working. 
this is single website specific problem, I wish I could share exact url but it wont be the stackoverflow way !... Anyways the solutions(work around) I have implemented is, entering partial text and then selecting exact match from drop down suggestion box... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Issue is specific to website i am working with..
- could not find specific solution to the problem
- I have implemented a work around which selects the correct value from suggestion box

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all your keyboards but the English one and then try again.
I've had the same problem and this worked for me.